# Creating directories from list preserving whitespaces

Tags: bash, awk, whitespace

I have list of names in a file that I need to create directories from. The list looks like

```
Ada Lovelace
Jean Bartik
Leah Culver
```

I need the folders to be the exact same, preserving the whitespace(s). But with

```
awk '{print $0}' myfile | xargs mkdir
```

I create separate folders for each word

```
Ada
Lovelace
Jean
Bartik
Leah
Culver
```

Same happens with

```
 awk '{print $1 " " $2}' myfile | xargs mkdir
```

Where is the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `gnu xargs` you can use `-d` option to set delimiter as `\n` only. This way you can avoid `awk` also.

```
xargs -d '\n' mkdir -p < file
```

If you don't have `gnu xargs` then you can use `tr` to convert all `\n` to `\0` first:

```
tr '\n' '\0' < file | xargs -0 mkdir
```

Answer (score 2):

@birgit:try: Completely based on your sample Input_file provided.

```
awk -vs1="\"" 'BEGIN{printf "mkdir  ";}{printf("%s%s%s ",s1,$0,s1);} END{print ""}'   Input_file | sh
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{ system ( sprintf( "mkdir \"%s\"", $0)) }' YourFile
# OR
awk '{ print"mkdir "\"" $0 "\"" | "/bin/sh" }' YourFile
# OR for 1 subshell
awk '{ Cmd = sprintf( "%s%smkdir \"%s\"", Cmd, (NR==1?"":"\n"), $0) } END { system ( Cmd ) }' YourFile
```

- Last version is better due to creation of only 1 subshell.
- If there are a huge amount of folder (shell parameter limitation), you could loop and create smaller command several times